# Installing package with NuGet with a specific framework version

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Each time I want to install a package with NuGet, depending of the package, a lot of differents versions of the package are installed.

For example, if I try to install Ninject, when I go to the folder 'packages/Ninject/lib', I have a folder for each version of the framework that the creator of the libraries supported.

[image]

Must I have to delete all folders manually that I don't want or is there any feature to prevent having folders created that have a different version of the framework than my project?

Comment: i was not able to find solution. so I just delete all except latest .net standard assemblies https://github.com/dzmitry-lahoda/installing-package-with-nuget-with-a-specific-framework-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet package is always extracted fully on disk. When installing into specific projects, we reference the one that matters for your project. We haven't invested the time to only unpack what's required for the project being installed since most people don't commit their packages to source control ( http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages ). Also, harddrive space is cheap :).

Comment: Any updates on this, by chance? This really freaks me out and I'm on the verge of submitting a pull request that does exatly this.

Comment: Why does it freak you out?

Comment: For one, I'm a stong proponent of keeping _everything_ that's needed to build my solution inside a VCS repository. Second, honestly can't understand why would I ever need Windows Phone or Sliverlight assemblies when all I do is build ASP.NET MVC webapps. Third, having this many binaries bloats up Mercurial repository.

Comment: Agree with Anton here.  The case for putting dependencies under source control isn't unusual and is similar in concept to the ideal of bin deployable apps.  There is something very strange about the package manager knowing and referencing the correct version, but keeping all other platform/framework versions around when obviously unused.  Hard disk space is cheap, but extra, completely unnecessary files do add up not only in space, but transmission time, especially when under source control.

Comment: Fortunately in ASP.NET 5 packages are globally cached by default. They aren't even in your source folder. Disk space is cheap and efficient use of disk space is even better :D. If you do want to commit packages to source control though then more power to you but IMO, it's just a bad idea

Comment: It is important when you use nuget for deploying something.
We have here a problem, where i want to add for example "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" to a .net4 service which is deployed over a nuget package and hosted in own appdomain. when i know want to install it, it searches packages which are only relevant to .netcore.
`

Comment: i am trying to use nuget with unity. i have to clean up packages folders manually so that unity avoids double load of same assembly.